# Extract multiple 'p' from within a 'div'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I was hoping to get some help on a problem that I'm having using BeautifulSoup.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/s/sosasa01.shtml"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
results = soup.findAll("div",attrs={"class": "p1"})
second_results = soup.findAll("div",attrs={"class": "p2"})
for x in results:
    print(x.find('p').text)
for x in second_results:
    print(x.find('p').text)
```

Within class "p1", I'm trying to get the text in between all <p tags, but I can only get the first p within each class. I appreciate any help that you guys could provide.

[photo of HTML I'm trying to scrape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2n2R4.png)

Comment: What is the output of `x.findAll('p')`?

Comment: The `.find()` method returns only one result.  Perhaps you meant to use `.find_all()` instead?

Comment: @arsho This is the output: [<p>58.6</p>, <p>8813</p>, <p>2408</p>, <p>609</p>, <p>.273</p>]

Comment: Is it what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You only `find()` one `<p>` instead of `findAll()` `<p>`:

```
for x in results:
    for p in x.findAll('p'):
        print(p.text)
print("--- second")
for x in second_results:
    for p in x.findAll('p'):
        print(p.text)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate your help!